# Reading DSL data file in python

Tags: python-3.x, dsl

Is there a way read the data file generated in dsl format from a simulation to read and perform analysis in python. Below I have attached a file in .dsl format from a simulator and want to read the generated data in python to perform data analysis, but have no clue for extracting the data from the file. Any help will be highly regarded.
Link to dls file: [simulated data in dls format](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l74wo6ljl6wfufz/PDB4213_Jan2018_G2_Drilling_Deviated.dsl?dl=0)

Comment: Check this out https://gist.github.com/McMartin/07f02c287a40ed317df7570071cc1eb7

Comment: No use, could you possibily check at your end if you could extract data out of the file uploaded.

Comment: Can you share how you stored the data after simulation? The tool/code that created this file, if possible host it into github, I will see what I can do and if something Works I will give a pull request.

Comment: The simulator is a commercial one(drilling simulator) with minimum access to its data generation and code side.

Comment: It i s named Drill Sim 5000

Comment: The .dsl file generated by it is a custom format and I was not able to find any documentation on how it stores values, what I do know is this is an ObjectDump, so unless a blueprint is available, I don't think it can be done.